# Vertically positioning a div with a smaller height than a div it is inline with

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` of assigned height next to a `<div>` of variable height depending on the amount of text inside of it. I've managed to get them next to eachother without the right-most `<div>`'s text wrapping around and underneath the left `<div>`, but I can't figure out how to get the left `<div>` to align with the top/start of the right `<div>`

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class='success'>
              <span class='introduction'><h4>Some instructions:</h4></span>
                  <div class='success-instruction'>
                    <div class='circledNumber'>1</div>
                    <div class='success-details'>
                      <h4>Do stuff:</h4>
                      Assign devlepment devices, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='success-instruction'>
                    <div class='circledNumber'>2</div>
                    <div class='success-details'>
                      <h4>Set up Things:</h4>
                      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='success-instruction'>
                    <div class='circledNumber'>3</div>
                    <div class='success-details'>
                      <h4>Be a hero: </h4>
                      Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. 
                    </div>
                  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.success { 
 display: block;
}
.success .introduction{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.success  .success-instruction {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.success  .circledNumber {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  text-align: center;

}

.success .success-details{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}

.success h4{
  display: inline;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/3wbcunm7/1/

Comment: I think that space is because of the line height of the text. add margin-top to the numbers equal to the font-size minus line-height / 2

Comment: Adding `margin-top` to `.success .circledNumber` just seems to be pushing the lower `<div>`s down. Did you mean to a different class?

Comment: Maybe a negative margin-top for the text will do it. I'll give it a try.

Comment: This is not a great solution but it does work. Add margin-top: -2; and it will be aligned.

Comment: Put that all in a table and set vertical-align: text-top;

Comment: @Korgrue technically would work but last time I used tables to align things my lead nearly lopped my head off

Comment: This is one of those circumstances where you are displaying tabular data - a proper use case for tables.

Comment: @Korgrue I'd say semantically, he should actually be using an order list.

Comment: Yeah, can do it as a OL, and attach the icons to the li items using a pseudoclass. A table seems like less markup due to the icons.

Comment: @Korgrue `::after` and `::before` are pseudo-elements not pseudo-classes. And yes, he should be using an `<ol>`. Remove the `list-style-type` from it, and use the `counter()` function, along with a pseudo-element.

Comment: @lamelemon I wanted to do an ordered list with custom `@counter-style` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style but our LESS version is out of date and "we don't have capacity in this sprint to update it." Oh well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this instance you can get away with just using `vertical-align: top;` on your icons.  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wbcunm7/2/).

Comment: BOOM perfect, works! Cheers. So simple. edit: will accept in 1 min, waiting for timer .

Answer (score 0):

It's not well aligned because of the line-height of the text.

```
.success .success-details{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  margin-top: -2px; /* 2 = (font-size - line-height) / 2  aprox. */
}
```

Note that this is not a very good solution since you will have to change the margin every time you change the font-size, line-height, font-family, etc.

Comment: Adjust alignment using fixed values like this is a really really bad solution ... and it has little to do with line height (in this case)